# Multiple forms Ajax request using MVC pattern, get the new values of input fields

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I'm retrieving forms from my page, using:

```
 DOMS = {
            form: '[data-form]', 
}

     document.querySelectorAll(DOMS.fom).forEach(function (form, index) {

                    arr[index] = {};
                    arr[index]['DOMRef'] = form; 
}
```

and adding them to an object. I add an event:

```
addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                    send(event, form);
                });
```

Later on form submit, I retrieve the form, and loop thru it:

```
form = arr[1];
for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
                if (form.elements[i].type !== 'submit') {
                    data = data + form.elements[i].name + '=' + form.elements[i].value;
                }
            }
```

Above, I'm creating an Ajax request data. The problem is that I always retrieve the first value(without refresh).

If I change the value of a form field, is ignored, I presume because I call it from the object, and not again from DOM. Something like refresh form.

But also I don't want if is possible to call the form DOM everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You are making copies of your forms somewhere, being called from object shouldn't affect.

```js
document.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
                    collectFormData(e);
                });
    
let formsArr = document.querySelectorAll("form");
let formsObj = {fArr: formsArr};

function collectFormData(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  //event.target
 var currForm = e.target;
 for(i=0; i<currForm.elements.length; i++){
 if(currForm.elements[i].type !== 'submit')
  console.log(currForm.elements[i].value);
 }
  //array
 for(j=0; j<formsArr[0].elements.length; j++){
  console.log(formsArr[0].elements[j].value);
 }
  //object
 for(k=0; k<formsObj.fArr[0].elements.length; k++){
  console.log(formsObj.fArr[0].elements[k].value);
 }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myform" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-datam">
    <input type="text" class="val1" name="val1" id="val1" />
 <input type="text" class="val2" name="val2" id="val2" />
 <input type="text" class="val3" name="val3" id="val3" />
 <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

PS. *But also I don't want if is possible to call the form DOM everytime* The value of the input field is in(side) the DOM. You can't get the gift without touching the package.